# How to solve passing value from one activity to another activity by using new intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing value from one activity to another activity by using a new Intent as like follows code but when I want to get the passing value from another activity it shows that the value is null.

First Activity from where the data is passing

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            Log.e("Pass Profile Name: ",""+profileName.getText());
            intent.putExtra("profileName",profileName.getText());
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
```

Second Activity getting the passing data code

```
String pName = getIntent().getStringExtra("profileName");
        Log.e("Profile Name",""+pName);
```

and the pName is null here.Can someone help me out why this is happened...

Comment: check returned value of profileName.getText()

Comment: I checked the return value by using a logcat and it's returned the correct value 
here's the log before putting the string 
Log.e("Pass Profile Name: ",""+profileName.getText());

Comment: @opu, please post all your code or at least the completed section where your are setting the extras and receiving it, it can helps to understand the big picture and maybe note a missing variable or something else. Also post the error trace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If profileName is an Edittext, you need to add .toString after you get the Editable profileName.getText()

Like this:

```
intent.putExtra("profileName",profileName.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I edited the code, but still shows null, don't getting the reason ... what behind this ...

Comment: Are you passing the data to a new Activity or you're passing it to an opened one and receiving it with onActivityResult?

Comment: I am passing it to new activity

Comment: Dear Brother, I have to check again.. may be I made mistake somewhere... whatever, many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this way

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,youractivity.class);
intent.putExtra("profileName",profileName.getText().toString);
startActivity(intent);
```

for recieving

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String pName = intent.getStringExtra("profileName");
```

Comment: did you check `profileName.getText().toString` getting values?